# How do you convert time series data with pandas and show graph via highstock

Tags: python, pandas, highcharts

I have some time series data as(financial stock trading data):

```
TIMESTAMP    PRICE     VOLUME
1294311545    24990  1500000000
1294317813    25499  5000000000
1294318449    25499   100000000
```

I need to convert them to OHLC values (JSON list) based on price column,ie,(open,high,low,close), and show that as OHLC graph with highstock JS framework.
The output should be as following:

```
[{'time':'2013-09-01','open':24999,'high':25499,'low':24999,'close':25000,'volume':15000000},
 {'time':'2013-09-02','open':24900,'high':25600,'low':24800,'close':25010,'volume':16000000},
 {...}]
```

For example,my sample have 10 data for day `2013-09-01`,the output will have one object for the day with `high` is the highest price of all 10 data, `low` is the lowest price,`open` is the first price of the day, `close` is the last price of that day,`volume` should be the TOTAL volume of all 10 data.

I know there is a python library pandas maybe could do that,but i still could not try it out.

Updated: As suggestion, i use resample() as:

```
df['VOLUME'].resample('H', how='sum')
df['PRICE'].resample('H', how='ohlc')
```

But how to merge the result?

Comment: Might help if you attach a sample of the data and the format you would like the output.

Comment: @mattexx, i have updated my sample and output requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you can only perform ohlc on a column/Series (will be [fixed](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/4740) in 0.13).

First, coerce TIMESTAMP columns to a pandas Timestamp:

```
In [11]: df.TIMESTAMP = pd.to_datetime(df.TIMESTAMP, unit='s')

In [12]: df.set_index('TIMESTAMP', inplace=True)

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
                     PRICE      VOLUME
TIMESTAMP
2011-01-06 10:59:05  24990  1500000000
2011-01-06 12:43:33  25499  5000000000
2011-01-06 12:54:09  25499   100000000
```

The resample via ohlc (here I've resampled by hour):

```
In [14]: df['VOLUME'].resample('H', how='ohlc')
Out[14]:
                           open        high         low       close
TIMESTAMP
2011-01-06 10:00:00  1500000000  1500000000  1500000000  1500000000
2011-01-06 11:00:00         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2011-01-06 12:00:00  5000000000  5000000000   100000000   100000000

In [15]: df['PRICE'].resample('H', how='ohlc')
Out[15]:
                      open   high    low  close
TIMESTAMP
2011-01-06 10:00:00  24990  24990  24990  24990
2011-01-06 11:00:00    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2011-01-06 12:00:00  25499  25499  25499  25499
```

You can apply [to_json](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) to any DataFrame:

```
In [16]: df['PRICE'].resample('H', how='ohlc').to_json()
Out[16]: '{"open":{"1294308000000000000":24990.0,"1294311600000000000":null,"1294315200000000000":25499.0},"high":{"1294308000000000000":24990.0,"1294311600000000000":null,"1294315200000000000":25499.0},"low":{"1294308000000000000":24990.0,"1294311600000000000":null,"1294315200000000000":25499.0},"close":{"1294308000000000000":24990.0,"1294311600000000000":null,"1294315200000000000":25499.0}}'
```

**This would probably be a straightforward enhancement for a DataFrame atm its NotImplemented.*

Updated: from your desired output (or at least very close to), can be achieved as follows:

```
In [21]: price = df['PRICE'].resample('D', how='ohlc').reset_index()

In [22]: price
Out[22]: 
            TIMESTAMP   open   high    low  close
0 2011-01-06 00:00:00  24990  25499  24990  25499
```

Use the records orientation and the iso date_format:

```
In [23]: price.to_json(date_format='iso', orient='records')
Out[23]: '[{"TIMESTAMP":"2011-01-06T00:00:00.000Z","open":24990,"high":25499,"low":24990,"close":25499}]'

In [24]: price.to_json('foo.json', date_format='iso', orient='records')  # save as json file
```

Comment: FYI in 0.13 to_json will take a date_unit='s' argument to put the epoch time stamps in seconds for example (0.12 writes these as ns since epoch)

Comment: @Andy, i have updated my question, could you help to check whether it is achievable with pandas?I'm new to both python and pandas:(

Comment: @SimonWang thanks for updating! I've just put a PR together to do the ohlc from a DataFrame https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/4740

Comment: @Andy, how about the 'volume', is it possible to count it for specific time range?

Comment: @SimonWang yup, just do the same but replace PRICE with VOLUME :)

Comment: @Andy, do you mean i need to first resample on PRICE then resample on VOLUME?

Comment: @Andy,price.to_json(date_format='iso', orient='records') will not export the TIMESTAMP index to the JSON output? The output here is as {"open":134.1,"high":134.1,"low":134.1,"close":134.1}

Comment: On,i'm sorry to miss the reset_index()!Yes, it just did the job!Thanks so much Andy~

Comment: @Andy,could you help to check how could i merge the VOLUME and OHLC DataFrames?

Comment: Don' forget to upvote helpful answers. You can just concat them, but I'm not sure this will make sense in this case (since one is a resample), since it's quite different to this you should ask as a new question. :)